# Transitive closure of identity relation

Tags: isabelle

I am not able to prove the the following `lemma` in [Isabelle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isabelle_(proof_assistant)):

```
lemma "Id^* = Id"
```

Any ideas on how to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an idea how this works you should first think about how you would prove this on paper. As you see by

```
term "Id"
```

`Id` is a set of pairs (type `('a * 'a) set`). Thus you have to show the equality of two sets. The canonical way to do so is by showing that each set is a subset of the other one.

Lets start with `Id^* ⊆ Id`. How to show that a set is a subset of another one? Exactly, show that every element of the 'smaller' set is also an element of the 'bigger' one, i.e.,

```
fix x y
assume "(x, y) ∈ Id^*"
then show "(x, y) ∈ Id"
```

Since the transitive closure is defined inductively we can do this by induction as follows

```
by (induct) simp_all
```

That is to say, use the default induction rule for a premise of the form `(_, _) ∈ _^*` (which happens to be `rtrancl_induct`) and then solve the base-case as well as the inductive-case by simplification.

Once again, the full proof

```
lemma
  "Id^* ⊆ Id"
proof (rule subrelI)
  fix x y
  assume "(x, y) ∈ Id^*"
  then show "(x, y) ∈ Id"
    by (induct rule: rtrancl_induct) simp_all
qed
```

The other direction is left as an exercise.

Answer (score 1):

If you just invoke sledgehammer (via the panel, or via `try`), then you immediately get the proof:

```
by (metis rtrancl_empty rtrancl_idemp)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still new to this. I guess that the whole Isar proof is something like:

```
lemma "Id^* = Id"
proof (rule equalityI)
  show "Id^* ⊆ Id"
  proof (rule subrelI)
    fix x y
    assume "(x, y) ∈ Id^*"
    then show "(x, y) ∈ Id"
    by (induct) simp_all
  qed
next 
  show "Id ⊆ Id^*"
  proof (rule subrelI)
    fix x y
    assume "(x, y) ∈ Id"
    then show "(x, y) ∈ Id^*"
    by (auto) 
  qed
qed
```

Comment: There's nothing to guess, when Isabelle accepts the proof it's fine ;)